# C++ function runs more than intended

Tags: c++, function

When I run my program the user can log in, but if the enter in a wrong user name, it runs a check username loop again, saying that they did not enter in a valid user name. This work perfectly fine except for one thing. Say they attempt to log in in three times and the third attempt is correct and the get prompted for a password. Once they input it it ask for a second password and then a third. It seems like it is completing the function for the other attempts. I can not think of a way to check for this. Any ideas.

***If you look at it you can see that I am calling `UserCheck` inside of `getNameIndex`. I am almost positive this is where the error is occurring.***

**The Function that checks the users:**

```
void User_Psw::UserCheck()
{
    // read from the database
    ifstream fin("dataBase.txt", ios::in);

    if( !fin.good() )
    {
        cout << "Failed to open database file." << endl;
        return;
    }

    while (fin >> username >> password)
    {
        Usernames.push_back(username);
        Password.push_back(password);
        ++sizeOfDatabase; // This may or may not be needed elsewhere.
    }

    // rest of the program
    cout << "Username: ";
    cin >> username;

    getNameIndex();

    cout << "Password: ";
    cin >> password;

    if(!PasswordMatches())
    {
        cout << "Access denied";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Success! You have logged in.";
    }
}
```

**This is the username check function**

```
void User_Psw::getNameIndex()
{
    userThere = false;

    for(int i=0; i < sizeOfDatabase; i++)
    {
        if (Usernames[i] == username)
        {
            index = i;
            userThere = true;
        }
    }
    if (userThere == false)
    {
        cout << "\nThat user name does not exsist. \n";
        cout << "Please try again. \n\n";
        UserCheck();
    }
}
```

Comment: You are absolutely right about the source of the problem, but it's not really an error, the program does exactly what you told it to do. You need to rethink the design of your functions. `UserCheck()` should handle all the input/output, `getNameIndex()` should not do any such thing, only validate the input and return a `bool` or the index of the user in the db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure of your program is wrong.

Instead of getNameIndex calling UserCheck() again, you should have getNameIndex return a bool - true on success, false on failure. Run it inside of a loop, something like this:

```
bool success = false;

while (!success)
{
 cout << "Username: ";
 cin >> username;

 success = getNameIndex();
}
```

Also, instead of having global variables, you should pass them to the function. Something like:

`success = getNameIndex(username);`

and `getNameIndex()` shouldn't do any I/O - the function that calls `getNameIndex()` should also be responsible for printing the error message. Imagine if you used `getNameIndex()` in a different context, such as when when the program is being run by another program or in an automated way - then printing to the console would be meaningless.

Comment: Thank you! I knew it had to do something with a bool to make it work but just couldn't quite figure it out! But that does make since.